# Simultaneous activation of two outputs in the 3 to 8 decoder

Tags: vhdl, decoder

I'm trying to build a Decoder3to8 using A Decoder2to4 using Vhdl. i have the following code for Decoder2to4

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Decoder2to4 is
Port( 
    A0, A1: in STD_LOGIC; 
    y0, y1, y2, y3: out STD_LOGIC
);
end Decoder2to4;

architecture Behavioral of Decoder2to4 is
begin
y0 <= not A0 and not A1;
y1 <= not A0 and A1;
y2 <= A0 and not A1;
y3 <= A0 and A1;
end Behavioral;
```

and this is the code for my Decoder3to8:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Decoder3to8 is
Port( 
    A0, A1, A2: in STD_LOGIC; 
    Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4, Y5, Y6, Y7: out STD_LOGIC
);
end Decoder3to8;

architecture Behavioral of Decoder3to8 is
component Decoder2to4 is
    Port( 
        A0, A1: in STD_LOGIC; 
        y0, y1, y2, y3: out STD_LOGIC
    );
end component;

signal B0, B1, B2, B3: std_logic;
begin
B0 <= (not A2) and A0;
B1 <= (not A2) and A1;
B2 <= A2 and A0; 
B3 <= A2 and A1;

Decoder2to4_0: Decoder2to4 port map (B0, B1, Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3);
Decoder2to4_1: Decoder2to4 port map (B2, B3, Y4, Y5, Y6, Y7);

end Behavioral;
```

The problem is when i give 0 as input to A0, A1 and A2, Y0 and Y4 become enabled. i think there is some problem with how i connect the signals but i can't see the problem.

Update 1:
I checked the inputs and found that it doesn't matter what value A1 and A2 are, in any case as long as A2 is equal to 0, Y4 will turn on and when A2 is equal to 0, Y0 will turn on.

Comment: my main assignment is to create this whole thing without Enable.
the Decoder2to4 is given and i need to use that to create Decoder 3 to 8

Comment: Gates on the Y outputs selecting Y0 - Y3 or Y4 - Y7 based on A2 or not A2. Seems you should relate your assignment directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `Decoder2to4` is a [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) encoder with this behavior:

[image]

And now you want to extend your implementation to support a 3-bit input:

[image]

You mention you are trying to do this using two instances of `Decoder2to4`. If you **absolutely must** use `Decoder2to4` to construct your `Decoder3to8`, then I think the key step is to note that the truth table of `Decoder3to8` contains two copies of `Decoder2to4`'s truth table, and the rest is all zeros:

[image]

To implement this in VHDL, my first tip would be to reverse the indexing in `Decoder2to4`. It is conventional to treat the lowest index (0) as the least significant bit, in which case the `A*` indexes in `Decoder2to4` should be swapped like this:

```vhdl
    y0 <= not A1 and not A0;
    y1 <= not A1 and A0;
    y2 <= A1 and not A0;
    y3 <= A1 and A0;
```

After that, you could replace the architecture statement area of `Decoder3to8` with this:

```vhdl
    Decoder2to4_0 : entity work.Decoder2to4 port map (A0, A1, B0, B1, B2, B3);
    
    Y0 <= B0 when A2 = '0' else '0';
    Y1 <= B1 when A2 = '0' else '0';
    Y2 <= B2 when A2 = '0' else '0';
    Y3 <= B3 when A2 = '0' else '0';
    
    Y4 <= '0' when A2 = '0' else B0;
    Y5 <= '0' when A2 = '0' else B1;
    Y6 <= '0' when A2 = '0' else B2;
    Y7 <= '0' when A2 = '0' else B3;
```

And that will implement the truth table above.

However, if it is not **absolutely necessary** to use `Decoder2to4`, then I would recommend a more generic approach. For example, you could generalize your implementation to support any input width by using standard array types like this:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity decoder is
generic(
    INPUT_WIDTH : POSITIVE
);
port( 
    A : in UNSIGNED(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    Y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2**INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0)
);
end decoder;

architecture behavioral of decoder is
begin

    process(A)
    begin
        Y <= (others => '0');
        Y(to_integer(A)) <= '1';
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

If you want to verify that this works correctly with an input width of 3, here is a minimal testbench:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture sim of tb is
    constant INPUT_WIDTH    : positive := 3;
    
    signal A    : unsigned(INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal Y    : std_logic_vector(2**INPUT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
begin
    
    -- Generate input
    process
    begin
        for i in 0 to 2**INPUT_WIDTH-1 loop
            A <= to_unsigned(i, INPUT_WIDTH);
            wait for 10 ns;
        end loop;
        
        A <= (others => 'X');
        wait;
    end process;
    
    -- Unit under test
    uut : entity work.decoder
    generic map(
        INPUT_WIDTH => INPUT_WIDTH
    )
    port map( 
        A => A,
        Y => Y
    );
    
end sim;
```

Comment: What [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [well asked programming question are you answering?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  "tip", "I would recommend" are indicative of opinion and reflect propping up a question you could be interacting with the Original Poster to improve.

Comment: @user16145658 I find the question to be acceptable and on-topic. If you find it to be unclear, then by all means ask for clarification. However, a SO answer receiving a downvote with the only offered objection being towards the question and not the answer is widely considered to be "counter-productive" and even "elitist" and acts to "alienate" other members (See: [Should I downvote attempted answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252003/should-i-downvote-attempted-answers-to-bad-too-broad-questions)).

Comment: "Downvoting purely because you believe the question itself is off-topic is in my opinion counter-productive." Search for supporting opinion in lieu of a specific programming problem may be counterproductive to[ the purpose of Stack Vverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292175/what-is-the-purpose-of-stack-overflow). *Questions and their answers are meant to act as a repository of knowledge: when you ask something, it shouldn't be "I can't figure out this assignment – help?"; rather, it should be about a specific problem that could be relevant to others in the future.*

Comment: The first 3 words of the [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) article are "In digital circuits", so I don't see a particular focus on Machine Learning. The first application listed there is "Digital circuitry" and, in the second sentence, I see "When using binary, a decoder is needed". Therefore, in my view, the relevance to this question is clear.

Comment: [Failure to comply with these guidelines is not a reason to downvote an answer.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) Naturally, i"f the answer is incorrect, low quality, poorly explained, and/or something that you would downvote anyway, then it is fine to do so. Remember that it's not always obvious at first glance that a question is homework, especially when you're not expecting to see it here. You can, according to your judgment, leave comments on the answer with suggestions on how to improve it."